An animated short that involved a green bug getting eaten
There's a weird animated movie that haunts my memories because I think it scared me as a child. 
It was in color and involved a bright green bug shaped sort of like a grasshopper.
He may have started out as a human and been cursed into the bug shape. I think most of the animation was him trying to avoid being eaten, but it ends with him in a stomach. It could have been at the beginning of a longer movie and was probably not more than ten minutes long. 
I saw it in the 90's/early 2000's, though it could be older than that. 
It was most likely of American origin, although I do not think there was any talking in the movie.
